# Responsive SVG sprites

Tags: svg, icons, sprite

I am building an icon system for a site and moving away from png and font-icon sprites to SVG.

I need it to work across all major browsers (IE9+) and ideally want to use fragment identifiers or, as a second best alternative, inline. I've done extensive research, and there isn't a great deal out there, and from what I have read SVG sprites aren't particularly responsive.

For fragment identifiers, using img tag, I have to set the width/height to the same size as the viewbox. Increasing the dimensions on the img tag ends up revealing some of the next sprite. I'd like to be able to use percentage values so the sprite fragment fills the parent container.

I just want confirmation that this isn't possible, I can't find anything that suggests I am wrong to think this.

Answer (score 1):

This is very much possible and is relatively easy to accomplish. SVG's are vector graphics and therefore, if done correctly, will be the most responsive graphics on your website.

Set your SVG file up as expected but put each sprite into a `<g>` tag with its own identifier.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g class="sprite" id="circle">
    <ellipse cy="50" cx="50" ry="45" rx="45" stroke-width="5" stroke="#00ff00" fill="#00ff00" fill-opacity="0.75" />
  </g>
  <g class="sprite" id="square">
    <rect y="5" x="5" width="90" height="90" stroke-width="5" stroke="#ff0000" fill="#ff0000" fill-opacity="0.75" />
  </g>
  <g class="sprite" id="triangle">
    <path d="M20,7 L92,50 L6,93 z" stroke-width="5" stroke="#0000ff" fill="#0000ff" fill-opacity="0.75" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Add some CSS to say only the rargeted one needs to be displayed

```
<defs>
    <style><![CDATA[
        .sprite { display: none; }
        .sprite:target { display: inline; }
    ]]></style>
</defs>
```

Then you can just call these out whenever required using an `img` tag or background element etc.

You can find the fully explained writeup here:

- [How to Use SVG Image Sprites](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-svg-image-sprites/)

Comment: Is that assuming each icon has the same width/height? My icon's dimensions vary

Comment: I've just tested it and I'm not getting the desired results when the icons have different dimension ratios, end up with unwanted whitespace . I think I will have to scrap the "dream" of using SVG sprites for now :(

Comment: I would have thought having a bunch of icons with the exact same dimension ratio was more unusual. Surely it would be more common that the width/height ratio will vary. Some will be square, most rectangular and with a different width/height ratio amongst those rectangles